# Yii createUrl for multilanguage website with slug urls

Tags: yii, yii-routing

I've followed [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/294/seo-conform-multilingual-urls-language-selector-widget-i18n/) guide for creating SEO-conform Multilanguage urls, now I need to fit url rules for a few modules using slug urls.

Used rule is working fine for reading urls, i.e. writing the url like

> www.mywebsite.com/en/pages/hello-world

(it loads the right page).

But using createUrl function it returns a valid url only if slug does not contains any dash, i.e. with slug "hello" createUrl returns

> www.mywebsite.com/en/pages/hello

but with slug "hello-world" createUrl returns

> www.mywebsite.com/pages/hello-world/language/en

This is the used rule:

```
'<language:(en|de)>/<controller:pages>/<slug:[\w\-]+>'=>'pages/view'
```

And I'm calling createUrl in this way:

```
createUrl('pages/' . $slug)
```

I can't figure out what's wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`'<language:(en|de)>/<controller:pages>/<slug:[a-z0-9-]+>'=>'pages/view'`

Comment: Try putting in your ´config/main.php´ like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650904/yii-framework-url-routing?rq=1

Comment: It's already in config/main.php, indeed it work for handling hardcoded  urls, but not for createUrl('pages/hello-world')

Comment: The `'<language:(en|de)>/<controller:pages>/<slug:[a-z0-9-]+>'=>'pages/view'` inside the main.php array will redirect any url how match the expression. So why you cant do that way?

Comment: It works for routing urls, it doesn't for creating url with yii function createUrl, that's my problem.

Comment: Check this link: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/404/hyphenation-of-routes-in-url-management/ see if can help